# Tomcat configuration for servlets

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I've installed Tomcat and I've been testing it: I wrote some .html and .jsp files and tried then in the server. They seem to work correctly together. For example: these files I'm trying allow me to upload a file to the server and writes its name in a database (MySQL). Once this is done I have a button that allows me to upload another file or I can consult the name of the files stored in the database.

My problem comes when I need to run a servlet. I'm trying a basic one:

```
package HelloWorldServlet;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void init(ServletConfig conf)
    throws ServletException
  {
    super.init(conf);
  }
  public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>Hello World</h1;>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
  }
}
```

From that I get a .class file. I put this file in: webapps/HelloWord/web-inf/classes

I really don't know how to modify the web.xml file and how to call this servlet from an .html or .jsp page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your web-inf directory **must be in upper-case** (WEB-INF).

Basic web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app 
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" 
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <servlet>
      <!-- 
        This is arbitrary name for your servlet,
        used in servlet-mapping below
       -->
      <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>

      <!-- Name of your servlet class -->
      <servlet-class>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>

      <!--
         Here you say location (under context) where your servlet
         can receive requests.
       -->
      <url-pattern>/hello-world</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Your web.xml must be saved in `<your-app>/WEB-INF/web.xml` path.

Now whenever browser will access http://localhost/HelloWorld/hello-world on your server, your servlet we be called, because it is mapped to `/hello-world`, and because your application is deployed in `HelloWorld` directory (thus mapped to /HelloWorld context).

Comment: Hi. I did everything as you said, now I'm getting a different error. When I pasted my code to this page I forog the first line : "package HelloWorldServlet;"

Does it make things different? If not I'll post the erros I'm getting. Thanks

Comment: @Charles - Adding a package changes the fully qualified class name of the servlet to HelloWorldServlet.HelloWorldServlet which needs to be in the file WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorldServlet/HelloWorldServlet.class

Comment: Imagine that the servlet described uses a method that belongs to a class (writeLog) included in the HelloWorldServlet package. Shold I put the writeLog.class in the same folder than HelloWorldServlet.class? Do I need to modify anything else? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Put it into same folder. You don't need to modify anything else.

Comment: Is it possible to have several classes  which extends HttpServlet in the same package? I tried that but I think I'm getting an error when I introduce that in web.xml.I don't know if I can do that in the same package (how should I modify web.xml then?) or if I define this class in a new package (web.xml is still a problem for me). Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you add more servlets (classes that extend HttpServlet), you need to also add `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` elements into web.xml for each new servlet. Btw, it would be better to ask new questions not via comments, but by creating new question directly. Only *I* am notified that new comment was added to my answer, but new *real questions* are prominently displayed on main page ... you would get answer faster ;-)

Comment: It doesn't matter that new servlets are in same package. What matters is full name of class -- you always need to write that name into `servlet/servlet-class` element. Full name of class includes package name, so if your `Servlet1` and `Servlet2` are in package `myservlets`, you will need to add new `servlet` element twice, first time with `<servlet-class>myservlets.Servlet1</servlet-class>`, and once with `<servlet-class>myservlets.Servlet2</servlet-class>`

Answer (score 1):

First you map the Servlet class to a name. Then you map the name to a url-pattern. The url pattern can be a single path or it can be a "globbing" pattern like /path/* or just /*

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="TestApp" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Test App</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```